# Ruby on rails (double rendering), (pause execution for 60 seconds), (then save to database) Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sleep

I'm trying to do the following:

- let user enter name, phone number and email.
- when he submits the form, he'll will be redirected to a waiting page
- the system will receive the response and wait for (60 seconds) before saving and notifying the user.

  ```
  def create
  render :wait
  sleep(60)
  @guest = Guest.create(params.require(:guest).permit(:name, :email, :phone)) 
  if @guest.save
      ## Here i was planning to notify the user
  end
  ```

my view directory views\guests(_form.html.erb, index.html.erb, wait.html.erb)

### I have 2 problems:

- 'wait' doesn't render immedietly, it sleeps for 60 seconds also although it's the first line inside (create) method.
- I don't know how to notify the user after saving the data to the database since i can't double render inside a method

I just started learning RoR yesterday for the first time, but i have to finish this challenging task today, help please.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Would it be okay to save immediately but still let the user wait? What should happen if the user closes the browser in between, do you still want to save the record after 60 seconds? Or do you only want to save the record if the user waited the whole time and is still online?

Comment: I was given this task as a challenge to be done in 48 hours, these are the task requirements:                                                                       - let user enter name, phone number and email.

- when he submits the form, he'll will be redirected to a waiting page

- the system will receive the response and wait for (60 seconds) before saving and notifying the user. @spickermann

Comment: Sidenote, not a fan of challenges like this. But I suppose whether you get the job or not it's a good learning excersise. Basically since you want the request to render immediately you have to fire the sleep and user creation in a background thread. Either make the front end request the creation status on a loop via a second endpoint or (better solution) use action cable / websockets

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in one request without involving real-time but what you can do is do it in two request one is the `render :wait` and then in the wait page you will in the on page load you send another request to the server which the new request will have your

```
sleep(60)
@guest = Guest.create(params.require(:guest).permit(:name, :email, :phone)) 
if @guest.save
    ## Here i was planning to notify the user
end
```